# Emgu CV imread changes resolution

Tags: c#, resolution, emgucv, tiff, imread

The code below works fine, it reads the Tiff image and retains the 16bit per channel depth but changes the resolution from 75 DPI to 96 DPI.
My application takes scanned radiographic film images where dose is related to darkening, so high resolution only creates noise.

```
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread(file, ImreadModes.Unchanged);
```

I have the ImreadModes set to unchanged but the resolution changes, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the dpi information from? I think not from the Mat object as Mat doesn't know anything about dpi.

Comment: It comes from the Bitmap part of Mat.